# Why does NSUserDefaults always return nil?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, data-persistence

I'm testing this code in playground. What I don't understand is, why is result always nil? Thanks for help

```
var value: String!
let key = "key24"

if value == nil{
    value = "hehe"
    let valueNS = NSString(string: value)


    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(valueNS, forKey: key)
}



var result: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key)
print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: I just tested your code in playground , it works fine and the output says the value of result is "hehe" not nil.

Comment: this is seriously weird. check out the screenshot

Comment: Don't use `setValue:forKey:`. Use `setObject:forKey:`.

Comment: now this is really weird bcz the code is working on my side

Comment: set object for key didnt help. I'm using xCode Version 7.0 beta (7A121l)

Comment: works in a real project. fine with me

Comment: BTW - why are you not using Xcode 7 GM? It's really important to stay current.

Comment: xcode versions change faster than weather :D downloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something screwy going on with playgrounds, especially with Xcode 7. I can get a variation on your code to work on Xcode 6.4, with a few changes:

You should use `setObject:forKey` not `setValue:forKey`.

You should cal synchronize after changing defaults.

Here's the modified code (which works in Xcode 6.4, although testing it in Xcode then causes Xcode 6.4 to fail as well.)

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var value: String!
let key = "key24"


if value == nil
{
  value = "hehe"
  print("value was nil!")
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(value, forKey: key)
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

var result = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(key)
print(result)
```

Comment: Calling `synchronize()` is both unnecessary and recommended against by Apple. It's never necessary to call in normal usage. Check the Foundation docs for the few instances in which it's actually necessary.

Comment: And yet when I tested it the stringForKey call returned nil without it, and returned the value correctly when I added it.

Comment: I'm going to go with the "ground truth" of what works.

Comment: Calling `synchronize` is only needed if you kill the app or the app crashes before iOS synchronizes `NSUserDefaults` for you.

Comment: I understand that that is what Apple says, but in this case adding the call to synchronize makes the second call to stringForKey return the correct value, while without it, you get nil.

Comment: Which makes no sense, as that's not how `NSUserDefaults` works. Any value added is immediately accessible. Perhaps it's an issue with playgrounds. In a real app it's unnecessary.

Comment: Probably so. Not sure how playgrounds interact with the app sandbox, bundles, etc. Not well, apparently.

Comment: I was getting nil every single time while retrieving from nsuserdefaults and synchronize did the trick...thank you

Comment: @user578386, So this odd behavior in playgrounds still exists in Xcode 7.3? Sigh...